# Problem uploading file with selenium webdriver + python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, file-upload

i have a problem uploading files with selenium and python. Tha main problem is the textbox where the file path is selected is disabled, so, when i put the absolute path in send_keys, this do nothing.

How can handle the dialog window with JS or another method (In my job, i can't install PyAutoIt or any framework)

The html code is this:

```
<div class="form-inline actions-toolbar">
        <input disabled="disabled" class="input-xxxlarge" id="uploadFile" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255); margin-left: 10px;" placeholder=""> --> This is the textBox
        <div class="fileUpload btn btn-primary">
            <span>Explorar</span>
        <input name="fileUpload" tabindex="1" class="upload" id="fileUpload" onchange="showPath(this);" type="file" size="50" accept=".txt"> --> This is the button "Search"
        </div>
        <input name="batchPaymentFilePath" id="batchPaymentFilePath" type="hidden" value="">
        <button disabled="disabled" class="btn" id="uploadButton" onclick="validNavigation = true;myFunction();"><i class="icon-upload-alt"></i> &nbsp;Cargar</button> --> Button to load File

    </div>
```

The python code is this:

```
    filePath = os.path.abspath('C:\\file\\path\\file_to_upload.txt')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@type="file"]').send_keys(filePath)
```

When i run the script, the upload file dialog window appears just showing the desktop, not the absolute file path.

Thanks guys!

Comment: before line on which you're sending filepath to the button , add this line n try : `driver.execute_script('document.querySelector("#uploadButton").removeAttribute("disabled");document.querySelector("#uploadButton").setAttribute("enabled", true);') `  and some `time.sleep(2)`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @sowjanya-r-bhat this is my update of the code that you share with me:

```
    driver.execute_script('document.querySelector("#uploadFile").removeAttribute("disabled");document.querySelector("#uploadFile").setAttribute("enabled", true);')
#Enable the file text box
upload = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="uploadFile"]')
#Send the file path
upload.send_keys("C:\\file\\path\\file_to_upload.txt")
#Enable Load Button
driver.execute_script('document.querySelector("#uploadButton").removeAttribute("disabled");document.querySelector("#uploadButton").setAttribute("enabled", true);')
```

I have to enable the load button, because depends of the file selected in the upload file windows.

Thanks again!